# CALayer zPosition ordering with extremely large values

Tags: ios, macos, core-animation

I've run into an issue where Core Animation is seemingly ignoring my values for `zPosition` when the values become large.

## Example

This can be replicated easily.

```
CGFloat largeZPosition = 1000000000;

CALayer *topLayer = ...
CALayer *bottomLayer = ...
bottomLayer.frame = CGRectOffset(topLayer.frame, 50, 50);

topLayer.zPosition = largeZPosition + 1;
bottomLayer.zPosition = largeZPosition;

// Intentionally sort the sublayers array in the wrong order.
rootLayer.sublayers = @[ topLayer, bottomLayer ];
```

With small values for the z-position, this functions as expected. Even though the sublayer array is not sorted correctly the top layer displays above the bottom layer, like so:

[image: correct]

However, with the example shown above, the result is as follows:

[image]

Obviously this is not correct.

## The Question

For my needs I'm unable to do manual sorting of the sublayer array, so therefore I'm relying on the `zPosition` to perform as expected. So my question is: how can I work around this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using such large values?  Are they overflowing the variable?

Comment: @Droppy: I'm attempting to layer items sequentially from top to bottom. Although not that many layer are on screen at once (that would be absurd), I do need the ordering to be ascending to potentially massive numbers. And no, overflowing does not seem to be the issue here.

Comment: How about floating point rounding issues?  Are you sure you aren't running into those?

Comment: From what I can tell, rounding issues don't seem to be occurring, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Add some `NSLog()`s of the `zPosition`s being set and it will become apparent pretty quickly.

Comment: Hmm, that is weird then.

Comment: When I simply tried to log `largeZPosition` and `largeZPosition+1` like this `NSLog(@"%f", largeZPosition+1);`, they both print as `1000000000.000000` (iOS Simulator)

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I was testing this on OS X.

Comment: From my testing (and from others) it seems like values at or above 2^24 seem to be behaving unexpectedly, at least on OS X. Values less than that function as intended.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That’s because QuartzCore seems to be converting `zPosition` to `float`, so it loses precision when `CGFloat` is `double`. IEEE single-precision floating-point numbers use 24 bits for significand precision, so integral numbers greater than 2^24 might not be represented precisely. For example,

```
float largeZPosition = 1000000000;
float largeZPositionPlus1 = 1000000001;
NSLog(@"%f %f %d", largeZPosition, largeZPositionPlus1, largeZPosition == largeZPositionPlus1);
```

outputs

```
1000000000.000000 1000000000.000000 1
```

The next precisely representable integer is 1000000064.

Note that `CALayer.zPosition` is defined as `CGFloat` and it is able to keep integral values larger than 2^24 precisely so long as the underlying `CGFloat` is able to do that. Inspecting

```
layer.zPosition = 1000000001;
NSLog(@"%f", layer.zPosition);
```

on 64-bit OS X, where `CGFloat` is `double`, outputs

```
1000000001.000000
```

so, at the `CALayer` public Objective-C class level, precision has not been lost. There is somewhere else in QuartzCore where conversion to single-precision `float` takes place.

I suggest using integral numbers (including the result of additions) that are less than 2^24. Given that `zPosition` has a floating-point type, you could use smaller fractional values instead of huge integral values.